# What makes some materials more reflective that others? (atomic level)

Tags: reflection

I am an A-Level student doing some research into beryllium. I have found it is highly reflective due to its free electrons re-emmitting EM waves. One thing i am stuck on however, is why beryllium is more reflective than other metals/materials and basically what causes a material to have a particular capability to reflect better than others.
Could it be that the more free electrons, the more waves/ photons can be reflected? Or is it to do with the molecular structure?
Any explanation would be much appreciated :)

Comment: In short: reflection involves absorbing a photon and turning it back into a photon *plus* [phonons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonon). The properties of the phonons essentially determine the properties of the reflected photons (through conservation laws). However, the properties and behaviour of phonons in different materials is a very complex subject that really requires quantum mechanics...

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plasmon